# Aggregate to custom (decimal) resolution

Tags: r, aggregate, resolution, r-raster

I have a raster of 30m cell size, with either value 0 or 1. I try to aggregate this into a 1000m cell size. I can then see the sum of '1's, in a 1000m cell size raster.

But the Aggregate function only lets me use a round number as a factor, so the closest I get is with factor 33x (to cell size 990m).

I would then need to resample 990m to 1000m but then obviously the values will shift and be incorrect.

Is there a way to use a decimal factor such as 33,3333, or better yet, use a raster with resolution 1000m as a template for the aggregation?

FOR ILLUSTRATION:

Here's an example of one aggregated cell sourced from 30x30m cells with 0/1 values, now in an aggregate raster at 990x990m cell size:
[image]
The two original cells are correctly aggregated into a 990x990m cell, and the sum of all values that were of interest (value '1') is 2. You can see these same two cells in the resampled cell on the right, in the top of the cell. But due to the resampling, the raster has shifted and includes more of the 30x30m cells. Yet, the cell value for the now resampled aggregate raster is still 2, while this is an incorrect value and should be 5.

Comment: I don't know the Aggregate function, but could you somehow multiply the values by 10 or 100, aggregate, and then divide by the same number?

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for the suggestion, I'm not sure how this would help though? Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: Without knowing the function, I'm shooting in the dark, but you wrote, "a round number as a factor", so if you increase your numbers by 10, then it may be the same as using a  decimal factor.  If this doesn't make any sense, then I'm wrong and can't help.

Comment: Ah right, I see what you mean. Unfortunately that won't help, the factor is by what factor you want to enlarge the cell size, not the values. So upscaling the values won't help in this regard. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Not sure how to implement, but this sounds like you're trying to implement spatial anti-aliasing. Here are two references that might help.
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing and https://kth.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1106244/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resample`.

Example data:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(crs="+proj=utm +zone=1", resolution=30, xmin=0, ymin=0, xmax=1020, ymax=1020)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
```

I first aggregate to a value close to what you want (in this example, I go from 30 to 100 m spatial resolution), and then use resample

```
a <- aggregate(r, 3, mean)
rr <- rast(crs="+proj=utm +zone=1", resolution=100, xmin=0, ymin=0, xmax=1000, ymax=1000)
b <- resample(r, rr)

r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 34, 34, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 1020, 0, 1020  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#name        : lyr.1 
#min value   :     1 
#max value   :  1156 

b
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 1000, 0, 1000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#name        :    lyr.1 
#min value   : 68.89777 
#max value   : 1103.335
```

You could also first disaggregate and then aggregate. With the above example you could do

```
d <- disaggregate(r, 3)
da <- aggregate(d, 10)

da
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 11, 11, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 1100, -80, 1020  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#name        : lyr.1 
#min value   :    43 
#max value   :  1093
```

Comment: The problem I have is that 1000 is not a factor of 30, and the function only allows decimal factoring, so I have to resample after aggregating, which falsifies my aggregate raster values. I have added in more context and illustration to my original post!

Also, in your example you say you go from 30m to 100m while you seem to use factor '3', which would bring you to 90m?

Comment: You can see that the result has 100 m resolution. Your illustration is not very helpful as it is just an image, there is no data. Perhaps first disaggregate and then aggregate is what you are after?

Comment: Hi Robert,

So I have a binary raster (30m), I'm using aggregate by sum to see the proportion of '1' values in a new, bigger raster (ideally 1000m). That is the ultimate goal.

But when using aggregate, it can only be done by whole number, so factor 33 will get me closest to 1000m (990m). But when I use resample afterwards to bring 990m to 1000m, the aggregate values are now wrong due to cell shifting.

First disaggregating would work I suppose, 30m to 10m and then 10m to 1000m, but in the function documentation I see no mention of a function options (I would need fun=sum)?

Comment: I think you could use "mean" with `aggregate` to get the proportion that is 1.

Comment: Yes, but would this also work the disaggregate function, not only the aggregate function?

Comment: No. disaggregate just splits the cells. You can of course divide with a constant after that, if appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was pretty simple, and I highly suspect the phrasing of my question was just not very clear, apologies for that.

When using the aggregate function (whether it is by mean, sum,...) you cannot resample afterwards and expect the agreggated values to still be correct. The values will be preserved, but because cells shift a little or a lot due to resampling, they will not be correct.

The trick as such, is incredibly simple: resample before you aggregate, not afterwards.